# Why are the contours elliptical near a max/min point but hyperbolic near a saddle point?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a feeling that perhaps elliptical contours means the surface is converging towards one point while hyperbolic contours mean that the surface is converging to a point, but only along a certain direction. I'm not sure if my intuition is correct so could someone please clarify this concept?

Answer (score 0):

A surface converging to a point doesn’t mean what you think. To clarify, here is an intuition of this concept, hoping you have hiked in hills or mountains before.

Think of walking in hills, while trying to not climb uphill or go downhill.

If you are close to the bottom of a hole, and walk while staying at the same height, you will turn around the hole, on a closed curve that looks like an ellipse.

On the contrary, if you are between two hills, slightly below a “mountain pass” (the saddle point), you will walk on the side of one hill, come close to the saddle point, and continue on the side of the other hill. This time it is not a closed curve, but looks more like a branch of hyperbola.